# Get error trying to connect segments(Bezier Curve)

Tags: bezier-curves

Trying to make this a raised image. I get the Error:"Cannot make segment" when I try to close it.

[image: As seen here]

Confused as to what I am doing wrong.

Edit: I have tried to use F to connect them and E Wow Alt-c did it THANK YOU

Comment: are you using Alt+C to close the curve, or what is your attempt? Please edit your question and describe your steps, thanks!